# gdal2tile problem geneting tiles

Tags: gdal2tiles, gdal-rasterize

Our problem is that we need to convert a shapefile to raster. Then, we need to generate tiles from zoom 15 to zoom 17 (2millions tiles to 16millions tiles).

Before we were using this methodology:

- Step 1 : Import shape in QGIS, then generate a raster
- Step 2 : Then we change the color/opacity of the raster using QGIS as well.
- Step 3 : we generate a new raster (tif) of 1Tera Byte (~1TB).
- Step 4: we use gdal2tiles to generate tiles.

This works fine. But the image is so big in size that it takes a while to tile.

But, now, we use directly GDAL as follows:

- Step 1: gdal_rasterize to convert a shape to raster in the right
  color/opacity
       with compression. It generates a raster of 1GB.

```bash
gdal_rasterize -of GTiff -co BIGTIFF=IFNEEDED -co COMPRESS=DEFLATE     
               -burn 102-burn 120 -burn 42 -burn 255 -co PREDICTOR=2          
               -co ZLEVEL=9 -ot Byte -a_nodata 255 -a class
               -ts 500000 500000 -l input C:/input.shp C:/output.tif
```

- Step 2: we want to generate tiles but gdal2tiles is hanging for a while just to generate a single tile. Maybe it does not support
  compressed file for tiling.

Any idea how to proceed?

Comment: This isn't very clear. Can you edit your question to show step-by-step what you've done, what the results were, and what you expected to happen instead. Right now, its hard to say what you are even asking.

Comment: Ok, we edit the previous post. Hope this is more clear for you now. Any idea?

Comment: You can see what gdal2tiles is doing by reading the python, but basically you are not doing this very smartly. If you compress the image (the `COMPRESS=DEFLATE` part, it'll have to be decompressed for each tile. Does it work better if you use `-co TILED=YES` in the `gdal_rasterize` step? It would be smarter to break up the geotiff at rasterize time, or to rasterize to a tiled format like geopackage.

Comment: even when we put '-co TILED=YES ' we get the same result ...can you explain me more how to process geopackage?

Comment: Just use -of GPKG and adjust the -co to be for that format (see help page).